# Bound DataGridView with combo box

Tags: c#, datagridview

For some reason, I can't find an answer to this question.

I have a DataGridView, bound to a list of objects.  Easy.  One piece of the data is a 'Filed Status', which can be 1 of 4 values.  I want the column that that displays which status it is to be a combo box with the available options.  Every example I see is adding a column to the grid.  I don't really want to add a column, I just want to limit the options on an existing column.

I have achieved similar results before by using the _EditingControlShowing event and using an AutoCompleteStringCollection for a textbox, but a user requirement is that it is a drop down list.

Comment: So you want a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, no?

Comment: Yes, but in the same spot in the grid, and still bound to the datasource.

Comment: You can add the columns yourself if you want to control/fine-tune their types. Note that you can and should add the list of values to the Items also. Also do read [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/column-types-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) on this topic : _Manually bound columns are useful, for example, when you want to replace an automatically generated column of one type with a column of another type._

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.